# How to define that node of TVirtualStringTree is presented on screen?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

It's easy to check that node is visible. But I don't know how to rightly define that node is presented on screen. I can find out only so:

```
BottomNode := Tree.BottomNode;
Node := Tree.TopNode;

IdBottomNode := Tree.AbsoluteIndex(BottomNode);

while Tree.AbsoluteIndex(Node) <> IdBottomNode do
begin
  Node := Node.NextSibling;
  if not Assigned(Node) then
    Break;
end;
```

(code without checking)

But I think it is rather rough way. May be is there more accurate way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may write a function like follows. The `Tree` parameter there specifies the virtual tree, the `Node` is the node for which you want to check if it's visible, and the `Column` optional parameter is the index of a column if you would need to determine whether the node and even column is visible in client rect:

```
function IsNodeVisibleInClientRect(Tree: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode;
  Column: TColumnIndex = NoColumn): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Tree.IsVisible[Node] and
    Tree.GetDisplayRect(Node, Column, False).IntersectsWith(Tree.ClientRect);
end;
```

But maybe there's a more straightforward way...

Comment: Thank you! Now it is the best way.

Comment: You're welcome! I've made a small change. You don't need to have any column in header. But as I said, maybe there's some ready made way for this.